# Save text from a href link threw javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to store a value to the cache using javascript when clicking an a href link. I'm setting up following code dynamicall

```
<a align="left" href="projectoverview.html">Test Manager</a>
```

So I want to save the text Test Manager to the cache, but I don't know how to catch this text when it's clicked. The code below is how that piece of code is setup. Do I need to add an onclick or something or is there a better way?

```
var text = '<a align=\"left\" href=\"projectoverview.html\">' + project['title']
                  + '</a><p align=\"right\">';
```

Comment: It seems like you are headed in the wrong direction. Do a bit of research on `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` to pass data from page to page with javascript. I normally use `sessionStorage` which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data from page to page using javascript/jquery you can do so with `sessionStorage`. Below is just an example of how you would do it using jQuery.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        var linkText = $(this).text();

        // Save data to sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('clickedLink', linkText);
    });
});
```

Then on the next page you can call it by using the `.getItem` function like so.

```
$(function() {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('clickedLink');
    alert(data);
});
```

If implemented correctly the alert box will say "Test Manager".

You can read more about `sessionStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

**EDIT:**

I would add a special class to those links though because the code above will execute on any link you have on the page which may give you unwanted issues.